# Progress dialog on only that particular view

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I use a lot of `AsyncTasks` but always like this:

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    //Create a Progress Dialog
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String info) {
    //Dismiss the dialog
    }
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //complete code to get data to be populated on the view
    }
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Show the dialog
}
```

But its like showing the progress dialog until I fetch the data and then populate all the View on the layout.

Instead I want it to be like, some data will be sent as Bundle, those can be used to populate their respective views and anything like a ImageView, whose Image is yet to be fetched must show a progress dialog.

Many apps like Amazon etc.., does this. Even the dialogs doesn't have any rectangular backround or text. How to do this?

Comment: display a temporary image and set the data to views. Once you download the data you can replace the image in the image view.

Comment: Actually not just `ImageViews`. I want to know how such progress dialogs are implemented

Comment: populate your views with dummy data. use asnctask to download and display the data in the views accordingly. Progressdialog can be displayed after setting the content to views. Once downloaded dismiss dialog and update ur ui with new data in onPostExecute()

Comment: But such `ProgressDialogs` will make the whole `UI` Inactive. I want the progress dialog to cover just that particular view and rest of the views must be visible and click-able.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to answer that question.